# Expanding CamelCase for readability using fontspec information

Tags: fonts, fontspec, expl3

I like to include font information in a colophon in some documents, and I'd like it to be automatic. I started by using the `\showfont` command that is used in various questions on this board, to wit:

```
\newcommand{\showfont}{
  encoding: \f@encoding,
  family: \f@family,
  series: \f@series,
  shape: \f@shape,
  size: \f@size
}
```

But the family provided by `\f@family` didn't correspond to the family I specified when I set it up, e.g., instead of "Source Sans Pro" it would give me "SoureSansPro(1)". I've tried to address this by learning a little `expl3`, but I'm stuck.  The MWE below defines a macro `\decamelize` that grabs the initial letters of an argument and inserts a space in between each lowerUPPER letter pair. It works fine on ordinary text, but fails when I use it on `\f@family`.

I'm very new at `expl3`. Among the many things I don't understand in this is that I need to use `\expandafter` for the MWE to run to completion, but even then it doesn't work the same way it does on ordinary text as input.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xparse}
\setmainfont{Source Sans Pro}

\ExplSyntaxOn

%% a function to change FooBarBaz10 into 'Foo Bar Baz'
\NewDocumentCommand{\decamelize}{m}
{
  \gtk_camel:n { #1 }
}

\cs_new:Nn \gtk_camel:n {
  % clear result queue
  \seq_clear:N \l_tmpa_seq

  % get the opening letters of the text
  \regex_extract_all:nnN { ^ [a-zA-Z]+ } { #1 } \l_tmpa_seq
  \seq_get_left:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l_my_tl

  % Insert a space into every lowercaseUPPERCASE character pair
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { ([a-z])([A-Z]) } { \1 \~ \2 } \l_my_tl

  \l_my_tl
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

%Now adjust \showfont to include the multi-word families
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\showfont}{
  encoding: \f@encoding,
  family: \expandafter\decamelize\f@family,
  series: \f@series,
  shape: \f@shape,
  size: \f@size
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

% This works, gives 'Source Sans Pro'
%\decamelize{SourceSansPro(10)}

%this does not work when \f@family is provided 
\showfont Aa

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The macros `\f@encoding`, `\f@family` and so on can be considered as token list variables.

What you need then is to apply the “decamelizing” process to the contents of a token list variable. So the idea is to do

```
\cs_new_protected:Nn \gtk_decamelize:n { ... }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \gtk_decamelize:n { V }
```

so to be able to call

```
\gtk_decamelize:V \f@family
```

But this would require `\makeatletter`, so there's another handy variant available:

```
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \gtk_decamelize:n { v }
```

whereby you can call

```
\gtk_decamelize:v { f@family }
```

Note that your “decamelizing” function should be protected, because `\regex_...` commands aren't expandable. There's no need to split the token list: you can easily remove any `(<digits>)` trailing part.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{xparse}% no longer needed

\setmainfont{Source Sans Pro}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\showfont}{}
 {
  encoding:~\tl_use:c { f@encoding },~
  family:~\gtk_decamelize:v { f@family },~
  series:~\tl_use:c { f@series },~
  shape:~\tl_use:c { f@shape },~
  size:~\tl_use:c { f@size }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \gtk_decamelize:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  % Remove (<digits>) at the end
  \regex_replace_once:nnN { \([0-9]*\) \Z } { } \l_tmpa_tl
  % Insert a space into every lowercaseUPPERCASE character pair
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { ([a-z])([A-Z]) } { \1 \~ \2 } \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \gtk_decamelize:n { v }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\showfont

\end{document}
```

[image]

This isn't foolproof, though: for instance, DejaVu fonts don't have a space before ‘Vu’.

Comment: Thank you, what a great lesson in `expl`!

Answer (score 6):

Use this:

```
 family: \expandafter\decamelize\expandafter{\f@family},
```

First, two `\expandafter`s are processed with the result `\decamelize{SourceSansPro(0)}`, then your `\decamelize` macro is processed.

Comment: Interesting, and thank you! This is a super-simple fix of my code, but I learned so much from egreg's answer that I thought it was worth rewriting.

Answer (score 2):

If you pass the whole family token to your camel case function

```
  family: \decamelize\f@family,
```

You can arrange to expand the argument before the regex so

```
  \regex_extract_all:neN { ^ [a-zA-Z]+ } { #1 } \l_tmpa_seq
```

instead of `\regex_extract_all:nnN`

That variant isn't pre-declared so you also need

```
\cs_generate_variant:Nn  \regex_extract_all:nnN {ne}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You and egreg have gotten me genuinely interested in `expl`.